# In the Bevy Engine, how do I use &mut queries in the for-each system?

Tags: rust, bevy

When extending a basic example with the mutating of a component, I tried adding `&mut` to a component parameter in a system.  However, this triggered the `no method "system" found` error.

My code is here:

```rust
use bevy::prelude::*;

  fn setup(
      mut commands: Commands,
      asset_server: Res<AssetServer>,
      mut materials: ResMut<Assets<ColorMaterial>>,
  ) {
      let texture_handle = asset_server.load("icon.png").unwrap();
      commands
          .spawn(Camera2dComponents::default())
          .spawn(SpriteComponents {
              material: materials.add(texture_handle.into()),
              rotation: Rotation::from_rotation_z(0.0),
              ..Default::default()
          })
          .with(Player(0.0))
          .with(());
  }

  struct Player(f32);

  fn control_system(keyboard_input: Res<Input<KeyCode>>, player: &mut Player) { // <- mut added here
      let mut r = player.0;
      println!("hello");

      /*
      if keyboard_input.pressed(KeyCode::Left) {
          player.0 += 0.1;
      }

      if keyboard_input.pressed(KeyCode::Right) {
          player.0 -= 0.1;
      }
      */
  }

  fn main() {
      App::build()
          .add_default_plugins()
          .add_startup_system(setup.system())
          .add_system(control_system.system())
          .run();
  }
```

Looking at [Into foreach system](https://docs.rs/bevy/0.1.3/bevy/prelude/trait.IntoForEachSystem.html#tymethod.system) I admit that I don't fully understand how or why this doesn't work, so maybe I'm missing something basic!

Did I make a simple mistake?  Are people doing stuff to work around this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```rust
fn control_system(keyboard_input: Res<Input<KeyCode>>, mut player: Mut<Player>) {
    let mut r = player.0;
    println!("hello");
}
```

`mut entity: Mut<Entity>` seems to be the format.

Mut borrows an entity. In the docs [here](https://docs.rs/bevy/0.1.3/bevy/prelude/struct.Mut.html).

Answer (score 10):

We chose to use `Mut<T>` pointers exclusively in Bevy ECS because they let us track whenever a component has changed. This is what makes our "change tracking" queries work.

Query<&mut T> actually also returns a `Mut<T>` pointer.

We actually initially supported `&mut T` in for-each systems, but this returns an actual `&mut T` reference, which prevents us from tracking mutations of T. This creates a situation where people using `&mut T` can no longer trust the result of "change queries" like `Changed<T>`. Giving people the ability to accidentally (or intentionally) break out of change tracking didn't seem worth the slightly more intuitive `&mut T` in systems.

`Mut<T>` is a slightly non-standard api that enables really cool features. Its something many new users will hit once and think "ok thats a bit odd", but then they never need to think about it again.